# Is there an equation representing the movement of a longitudinal wave?

Tags: waves

Is there an equation, be it rectangular, polar, or parametric, that represents the movement of a longitudinal wave? Something like this:

> [image]
>
> taken from [How can a sine wave represent a longitudinal wave?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/17664/306084)

or like this:

> [image]

I am thinking that this can be done by a parametric equation $(x(t),y(t))$. Is the equation of this graph known already?

---

This is a question for identification of an equation, not a homework to find the equation of the graph itself as an exercise.

Comment: The wave equation addresses longitudinal waves too, not just transverse waves.

Comment: I mean, not the equation for all waves, but longitudinal waves in particular.

Comment: Yes, it is known. There are formulae for pressure, density and displacement. For example you can see https://feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_47.html section 47-3.

Comment: Are you referring to $$\frac{\partial^2\chi}{\partial x^2} = \frac{1}{c_s^2}\,\frac{\partial^2\chi}{\partial t^2}?$$

Comment: @soupless Yeah. This is in differential form and it's solution is sinusoidal.

Comment: I am aware that this equation encompasses longitudinal waves, including transverse waves, but what I am looking for is its rectangular/polar/parametric equation, not as a PDE.

Comment: @soupless Do you mean the propagation of longitudinal waves in 2 or 3 dimensions? In these cases, the final answer is more complicated, but yet exists.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128793/discussion-between-soupless-and-medvis).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### General wave parameterisation

The waves the animations are showing can be parameterised as
$$
\rho(x,y,t) = A \cos(k x - \omega t + \phi)~,
$$
where $\rho$ is the density of particles in the first animation and the amount of spring contraction in the second, $A$ is the amplitude of the wave, $k$ is the wave number in $x$-direction and $\omega$ the wave's angular frequency, so $\omega/k$ would be the phase velocity. Finally, $\phi$ is some constant phase shift which can always be set to 0 by choosing the origin of the coordinate system cleverly. This is the same expression as for transversal waves, only it is interpreted as density rather than displacement.

### About the first animation

If you are also interested in how the particles in the first animation behave, they are just harmonic oscillators, so their motion in $x$-direction obeys
$$
x(t) = B \cos(\omega t + \psi(x_0)) + x_0~,
$$
with $B$ as amplitude, $\omega$ as angular frequency, $x_0$ as equilibrium point and $\psi(x_0)$ as a constant phase which depends on the equilibrium point, because the wave has different phases at different points in space at a single point in time. In $y$-direction the particles obviously do not move at all.

### About the second animation

Considering the second animation, the spring can be parameterised as
$$
x(\chi,t) = \chi + A \cos(k \cdot \chi - \omega t)~, \qquad y(\chi,t) = \cos(\chi)~,
$$
where the parameter $\chi$ can be interpreted as some kind of "unperturbed $x$", the "perturbation" being responsible for the spring contracting and relaxing. The amplitude $A$ is the one of this oscillating motion, $k$ and $\omega$ are the wave number and angular velocity of the wave propagating through the spring and $t$, the second parameter, represents time.

Plotting and animating these equations yields this:
[image: spring wave simulation]
It behaves quite similar to the animation in the question.

Comment: Is it $\rho(x,y)$ or $\rho(x,t)$?

Comment: @soupless Sorry, I messed that up. Actually, $\rho$ is constant with respect to $y$, but in general it is $\rho(x,y,t)$. I'm going to change that.

Comment: Can you please go to the discussion room from the comment section?